# Run Prometheus custom exporter in a set frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x, prometheus

I want to get a python prometheus exporter running in a set frequency.

```
import time
import random
from os import path
import yaml
from prometheus_client.core import GaugeMetricFamily, REGISTRY, CounterMetricFamily
from prometheus_client import start_http_server
totalRandomNumber = 0

class RandomNumberCollector(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def collect(self):
        gauge = GaugeMetricFamily("random_number", "A random number generator, I have no better idea", labels=["randomNum"])
        gauge.add_metric(['random_num'], random.randint(1, 20))
        yield gauge
        count = CounterMetricFamily("random_number_2", "A random number 2.0", labels=['randomNum'])
        global totalRandomNumber
        totalRandomNumber += random.randint(1,30)
        count.add_metric(['random_num'], totalRandomNumber)
        yield count

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_http_server(9000)
    REGISTRY.register(RandomNumberCollector())
    while True: 
        # period between collection
        time.sleep(1)
```

However, this does not run in a loop every 1 second. I tried to call the `collect()` function like the below and it still doesn't work:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_http_server(9000)
    REGISTRY.register(RandomNumberCollector())
    while True: 
        ran = RandomNumberCollector()
        ran.collect()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Maybe I am missing something simple here, I want to run the exporter in a set frequency.

Reference - this blog: https://matthewzhaocc.com/building-a-custom-prometheus-exporter-in-python-6491d4cdcef3

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, after `REGISTRY.register(RandomNumberCollector())`, `start_http_server` invokes the classes (i.e. `RandomNumberCollector`'s) `collect` method every time it is invoked (i.e. `GET /`).

> **NOTE** Given the two `yield`'s, it's unclear to me why changes to the two metrics don't oscillate. I would expect the n<sup>th</sup> `collect` to return one `yield` value, and the n<sup>th+1</sup> to `collect` to return the other `yield` value.

The `while` loop in your code does not affect the metric values.

Actually, it's only function is to keep the process running so that the HTTP server continues, so that something can continue to scrape it.

What - I think!? -- you want is for the metric values to change on a frequency.

One way to do this uses threads. In Python, to do this using a single process (as you are) is more challenging because you will need create a(nother) thread (your code runs as one and the HTTP server is on another) that periodically updates the metric values.

Another way you could consider emulating this behavior without using threads, would be to keep a `last_update` time in the `collect` function and only generate new random values for the metrics if e.g. 1 second has passed since they were last read.

In practice, this scenario would likely manifest only if the collector and metric source were running in separate processes **and** possibly if collection were expensive, i.e. you'd want to limit the number of times Prometheus attempts to scrape the metrics because, each time the values are scraped, there's some cost to you.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Will try another way or just wrap it in a flask wrapper / Gunicorn so its easier for multithreading